In Genesis 3:22, does Adam make Eve the grammatical subject of her naming, or is that just the idiom of כְּנֶגְדֹּֽו=qara?
The question is are there some poetic effects in Genesis 2:23 in Ancient Hebrew. I'm not after a general explanation of the passage or why does Adam name Eve etc.
=================================
Genesis 2:23
וַיֹּאמֶר֮ הָֽאָדָם֒ זֹ֣את הַפַּ֗עַם עֶ֚צֶם מֵֽעֲצָמַ֔י וּבָשָׂ֖ר מִבְּשָׂרִ֑י לְזֹאת֙ יִקָּרֵ֣א אִשָּׁ֔ה כִּ֥י מֵאִ֖ישׁ לֻֽקֳחָה־זֹּֽאת׃
ləzōṯ yiqqare issa = this one shall be called woman
Adam has the task/privilege of giving names. Eve is the grammatical subject of her naming (notwithstanding it's a passive verb).

Is there a contrast with the livestock, birds and beasts? (and Seth)

Is it marked that Adam doesn't say to Eve "I name you."  ?

Does the passive construction convey verbal awkwardness?

Has Adam come close to saying she will name things?

Has he named her as if she was a city? [a gaffe? flattery?]

Is any pathos being created?


==
Genesis 2:20 - Livestock, Birds, Beasts
וַיִּקְרָ֨א הָֽאָדָ֜ם שֵׁמֹ֗ות לְכָל־הַבְּהֵמָה֙ וּלְעֹ֣וף הַשָּׁמַ֔יִם וּלְכֹ֖ל חַיַּ֣ת הַשָּׂדֶ֑ה וּלְאָדָ֕ם לֹֽא־מָצָ֥א עֵ֖זֶר כְּנֶגְדֹּֽו׃
qara is Strongs 7121. Active here
It seems relevant to compare Gen 5:3 where Adam names Seth.
==
Genesis 5:3 - Seth named by Adam
וַֽיְחִ֣י אָדָ֗ם שְׁלֹשִׁ֤ים וּמְאַת֙ שָׁנָ֔ה וַיֹּ֥ולֶד בִּדְמוּתֹ֖ו כְּצַלְמֹ֑ו וַיִּקְרָ֥א אֶת־שְׁמֹ֖ו שֵֽׁת׃
There is אֶת־ (direct object marker) for Seth, and the verb matches that of 2:20 above, so this is the same construction as for the creatures.
==
Genesis 4:25 - Seth named by Eve
וַיֵּ֨דַע אָדָ֥ם עֹוד֙ אֶת־אִשְׁתֹּ֔ו וַתֵּ֣לֶד בֵּ֔ן וַתִּקְרָ֥א אֶת־שְׁמֹ֖ו שֵׁ֑ת כִּ֣י שָֽׁת־לִ֤י אֱלֹהִים֙ זֶ֣רַע אַחֵ֔ר תַּ֣חַת הֶ֔בֶל כִּ֥י הֲרָגֹ֖ו קָֽיִן׃
Before when Eve had named Seth, the same phrasing was used.
=================================
"Was Called"
Strongs has 700+ usages of qara
18x translated as Passive : {Genesis 11:9} (city) ; {Genesis 16:14} (a well) ; {Genesis 19:22} (city) ; Genesis 25:26 (Jacob) ; Genesis 25:30 (Edom) ; {Genesis 35:8 (an oak)} ; Genesis 38:29 (Perez) ; Genesis 38:30 (Zerah) ; {Genesis 50:11 (place)} ; {Exodus 15:23 (place)} ; {Numbers 11:3 (place)} ; {Numbers 11:34 (place)} ; {Numbers 13:24 (place)} ; {Numbers 21:3 (place)} ; {Deuteronomy 3:13 (place)} ; {Joshua 7:26 (place)} ; {Judges 1:17 (place)} ; {2 Samuel 2:16 (place)}
14x Towns, places, and wells can only be named in the passive, so those usages don't help with Genesis 3:22
4x Humans as subjects
Genesis 25:26 (Jacob) - prophet
Genesis 25:30 (Edom) - =Esau, progenitor of the Edomites (red hair)
== == == ==
Genesis 38:29 (Perez) - ancestor of David
Genesis 38:30 (Zerah) - patriarch (red ribbon)
These four are all aetiologies of (male) names. But they are also all in Genesis and might be referring back to Eve, as marked. So it's neither safe to say "Genesis 3:22 is a special usage" nor "Genesis 3:22 is the normal usage/a common formula". Eve is the only woman who "is named" but there's not a big enough sample to say that's a unique honour.
But the four males are all extremely important figures; and they are two pairs of twins (so perhaps more like a single usage). This suggests "is named" is reserved to cities and individuals who contain that many people ancestrally. Later in Genesis 3:20 is "the mother of all the living", but has Adam guessed that?
Edom might fall in two camps since he went on to found an eponymous city.
So perhaps worth checking authorship? - e.g. if leaders adding their ancestors into Genesis for propaganda was a thing.
=================================
Other past discussions of this passage. (but they don't contain what I need)
Why does Genesis 3 use male pronouns for Eve?
How should Genesis 3:20 be rendered?
Who names Seth?

Was there a typo with the scripture reference at the top? Is it not Genesis 3 verse 20 where Adam names the woman "Eve", in faith, believing what God said of her? The question asks about Genesis 3:22.
